# Getting an "Object #<NodeList> has no method 'click'" error?

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to add some multiple form fields in separate divs. But by adding some divs with buttons i get the following error when i click a button within a div:

> Object # has no method 'click'

I get this error when i move the `</form>` tag under a second or third div. I don't get an error when i put the `</form` right under my first div. The form has a total of 4 divs all with a bunch of buttons.

The next button just shows the next bunch of buttons (simple jquery slideup/slidedown). Each button triggers a function called `win()` like so

```
<input type=button class="team round1" value="a1" name="WIN0_1" onclick="win(this)"/>
```

Now per div i have given some buttons the same name (for example: `name="WIN0_1"` exists 4 times)

Sorry for this chaotic post, but i hope someone has a suggestion

PS: as for the form in seperate divs i followed [this](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery/) tutorial.

Comment: need some code, can't tell what's wrong here. what does the `win()` do?

Comment: hi manuel, http://jsfiddle.net/123js/Xm5Rt/ and the last line seems to cause the error when i put </form> under a second div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alright so based on you code http://jsfiddle.net/123js/Xm5Rt it looks like by copying the div's with input's you get a collection of buttons on this line:

```
var winnerButton = winner.form.elements["WIN"+nextlevel+"_"+nextgame];
```

so `winnerButton` isn't 1 but multiple buttons.

when trying to trigger a `click()` on a collection of elements you get the error you mentioned.

The solution could be many things... To know sure you have to post the complete html (form + div's + input's) so we could have a beter look.

Comment: ...your suggestion help me out a lot.

Answer (score 3):

A `NodeList` object is a collection of `Node` objects, usually returned by `childNodes` or `getElementsByTagName`/`getElementsByTagNameNS`.  Search your code for `.click(` and you will likely find that it is attached to an object whose value is the result of one of those operations, rather than a jQuery object as you were expecting.

You can easily reproduce this error to understand what I mean by typing the following in your JS console:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div").click();
```

If you're struggling to find the cause of the problem, then you need to post your code.

Comment: tx andy i think i understand what you mean, i think you are rihgt about the jQuery object. but the error doesn't appear when i just have one div?

Comment: @alex: I can't help you there unless you post the full code, unfortunately.  I can only tell you where to start looking ;-)